# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED And Domain refused to connect

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, custom-domain

I'm trying to connect WordPress instance on google cloud with the custom domain but I'm having this error

```
This site can’t be reachedquotivy.com refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

What I found it wired is that the domain is working on Tor browser and not working on Chrome and Safari, and I tried to take an online screenshot from it and it's working & I ping the domain and seems working too! not so sure what to debug or do to fix this bug!

This is a sample URL: https://quotivy.com/rumi/when-the-world-pushes-you-to-your-knees/

How it looks like on my browsers:
[image]

Custome DNS on my google cloud
[image]

Comment: I've checked you domain and found no issues at all. GCP Firewall and GCP Cloud DNS were configured correctly. Do you still have this issue? Have you tried to check from different PC or mobile phone?

Comment: Most likely you did not wait for DNS to propagate. This can take a few hours after creating or changing the DNS resource records.

Comment: If Domain, DNS, and virtual hosts are set up correctly and it still shows this error then try checking file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have moved the site recently then check in your database (either domain.com/phpmyadmin or SSH if Cloud SQL) for references to the old domain and update to the new domain. This includes moving from http to https

In GCP Compute Engine VM Instance settings, make sure to allow http and allow https traffic. You may want to assign a static IP in GCP Console > VPC Network > External IP addresses

Lastly you may need to update etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf to make sure your servername matches your WordPress domain name